# Algebra help on Summation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

The following is my professor's time complexity for insertion sort. I need help on the summation part.

Please can someone help me understand the distribution of the $c_5$ and $c_6$ constants throughout the solution? I don't understand why they are subtracted on the $\times(n)$, and then added at the end.
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n)
&= c_1 n + c_2 (n-1) + c_3(n-1) + c_4 \sum_{j=2}^n t_j + c_5 \sum_{j=2}^n (t_j-1) + c_6 \sum_{j=2}^n (t_j-1) + c_7(n-1) \\
&= (c_4 + c_5 + c_6) \sum_{j=2}^n t_j + (c_1+c_2+c_3-c_5-c_6+c_7)n+(-c_2-c_3+c_5+c_6-c_7)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Would be nice if you put a little effort writing it down properly in LaTex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a term (after the first equality sign) that looks like
\begin{equation}
c_{5} \sum_{j=2}^{n} (t_{j}-1)
\end{equation}
This can be expanded quite easily since the $-1$ term will subtract $n-1$ (since you are summing from $j=2$ to $n$) copies of $c_{5}$ from the summation. Hence
\begin{equation}
c_{5} \sum_{j=2}^{n} (t_{j}-1)=c_{5} \sum_{j=2}^{n} t_{j}-(n-1)c_{5}
\end{equation}
Which goes some way to explaining the terms after the second equality sign since the above can be re-written
\begin{eqnarray}
c_{5} \sum_{j=2}^{n} (t_{j}-1) &=& c_{5} \sum_{j=2}^{n} t_{j}-(n-1)c_{5}
                               &=& c_{5}\sum_{j=2}^{n} t_{j} +c_{5} - nc_{5}  
\end{eqnarray}
The term $c_{5}-nc_{5}$ now appear in the last line to your calculation.

Hope that helps, if not give me a shout.

Best,
A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Autolatry, I was wondering how do you write all the symbols, I mean take a look at the un-edited original post I had submitted, it was a picture of the equations to which Alexwlchan turned into nice and more readable characters.

Comment: I think the langauge of choice os MathJax, a link to which can be found here http://www.mathjax.org/ Personally I would call the language LaTex, which is the syntax I used as a student. Cheers!